# problem with xsl apply-templates

Tags: xml, pdf, xslt, pdf-generation, apache-fop

It seems that my template is never called but the for loop works correctly.

It prints "test" exactly the number of times the "car" node exists but "doStuff" doesn't seem to be accessed and "test2" is never outputted. Any ideas?

```
<fo:table-body>
      <xsl:for-each select="car">
      test
  <xsl:apply-templates select="car" />
  </xsl:for-each>
</fo:table-body>
```

....

```
<xsl:template match="car">
<fo:table-row height="0.40cm">
test2
dostuff()....
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because you're trying to apply a nested car...

The `for-each` already changes the context, so that you have to apply the template on the current node:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
```

Answer (score 4):

Within the for-each, "car" is the active node, and since by default the `select` attribute on `apply-templates` searches the descendants axis, it's trying to select "car" elements that are children of the active car element.  Try

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
```

instead.